# Find general solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$ \frac{d}{dx}[(3x+1)\frac{du}{dx}] = 0 $$

Hint, expanding the derivative cannot solve it. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Observe
\begin{align}
(3x+1)\frac{du}{dx} = C
\end{align}
for some constant $C$. Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{C}{3x+1}.
\end{align}